# How to Parse byte array to Image (ByteArray from json responce)

Tags: android

i'm getting below string from jsonresponse,

```
String s="[137,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0,0,13,73,72,68,82,0,0,0,117,0,0,0,117,8,6,0,0,0,112,4,174,188,0,0,0,1,115,82,71,66,0,174,206,28,233,0,0,0,4,103,65,77,65,0,0,-------------------------- ];
```

like this, i'm not able yo post whole string because of character limitation so,

```
try{
            byte[] a=s.getBytes();

            System.out.println("Size "+a.length);

            ImageView iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds=false;


            Bitmap decoded_photo_byte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(a,0,a.length,options);

            System.out.println(" bitmap"+decoded_photo_byte);

            iv.setImageBitmap(decoded_photo_byte);

        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

but image not shown, instead i'm getting 07-01 14:35:44.181: D/skia(10239): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null

Comment: `byte[] a=s.getBytes();` - this works not the way you expect, this line will break the string "[1,2,3,4]" into bytes, but not convert it to byte array [1,2,3,4]. You should convert it manually.

Comment: How to convert it manually ? @Scadge

Answer (score 0):

photodata is your data which you recieve from json;

```
 try {
        byte[] data = android.util.Base64.decode(photodata, 0);

        Bitmap bmpNew = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        profilepic.setImageBitmap(bmpNew);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: No raj, i'm getting byteArray not a base64 string .... 

i was tried your code but getting 

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64

Answer (score 0):

```
String s="[137,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0,0,13,73,72,68,82,0,0,0,117,0,0,0,117,8,6,0,0,0,112,4,174,188,0,0,0,1,115,82,71,66,0,174,206,28,233,0,0,0,4,103,65,77,65,0,0,-------------------------- ]";

String[] s2 = s.substring( 1, s.length - 1 ).split( "," );
byte[] a = new byte[s2.length];
for( int i = 0; i < s2.length; ++i ) {
  a[i] = Byte.parseByte( s2[i] );
}
```

Comment: @Sangharatna, are you sure that your string is like "[1,2,3,4]"? From where do you get (retrieve) it?